# Netlify + Middy. Does not return response to client side

Tags: netlify

i'm trying to create a middleware for my `netlify-lambda` functions using `middy`. The middleware suppose return response to my api call if it met a false statement and prevent from execute the function. And the response could not return to the client side.

**func.js**

```
import withAuth from './middleware/auth';
import middy from '@middy/core';

const func = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  try {
    console.log('func');

    // ... the function
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('locationCreate', error); // output to netlify function log
    callback(null, statusCode: 500, body: JSON.stringify({error}));
  }
};

exports.handler = middy(locationCreate).use(withAuth());
```

**middleware.js**

```
const withAuth = () => ({
  before: (handler, next) => {
    const { authorization } = handler.event.headers;

    console.log('authorization', authorization);

    if (!authorization) {
      console.log('No token from browser');
      return handler.callback(null, (statusCode: 400, body: JSON.stringify({message: 'Token not found'}));
    }

    return next();
  },
});

module.exports = withAuth;
```

I tested by using Postman, and it prints the 'No token from browser' but it just stuck at 'Sending request'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who are doing middleware in Netlify dev, avoid using `statusCode: 404` as it will cause your server to stuck forever.

This problem is mark as bug in Netlify. Reference:
[Netlify dev server hangs if function returns 404](https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/695)